# How to add an interceptor to a particular method using Ninject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

To intercept a particular method with Ninject, I do this:

```
[MyInterceptor] void MyMethod()
```

or this:

```
Kernel.InterceptAround<IMyClass>(c => c.MyMethod(), inv => { ... }, inv => { ... });
```

I want to add all interceptors in a single place like (kernel config) and keep `MyMethod` free from any attributes. However, this `Kernel.InterceptAround` signature accepting `Action` instead `IInterceptor` looks weird! I would prefer full control of method execution.

Is it possible to add an interceptor for a particular method (not for a type at all!) without attributes, probably with Ninject extension? I mean a syntax like this:

```
Kernel.Intercept<IMyClass>(c => c.MyMethod()).With<MyInterceptor>();
```

Filter by method's name inside the interceptor is not a good option. Feel free to suggest another DI container.

Comment: I know nothing about Ninject, but what's wrong with implementing syntax you are looking for?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov of course I can pass interceptor's methods as arguments... but then I need to manually create such objects and manage its lifetime... the code will look bad for the hundreds of interceptors. Let's DI container do it instead of me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would prefer full control of method execution

While `InterceptAround` allows you only to specify what happens before and after execution, `InterceptReplace` can give you full control by allowing you to invoke `IInvocation.Proceed` manually (or not invoke it if you want).

Here is an example:

Create an interceptor like this:

```
public class Interceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        //Do before

        invocation.Proceed();

        //Do after
    }
}
```

And then you can use the `InterceptReplace` method like this:

```
var my_interceptor = new Interceptor();

Kernel.InterceptReplace<IMyClass>(
    c => c.MyMethod(),
    inv => my_interceptor.Intercept(inv));
```

You can create extension methods to help you get a different syntax that you like. Here is an example:

```
public static class MyExtentionMethods
{
    public static void UseInterceptorFor<T>(
        this IKernel kernel,
        Expression<Action<T>> methodExpr,
        IInterceptor interceptor)
    {
        kernel.InterceptReplace<T>(methodExpr, inv => interceptor.Intercept(inv));
    }
}
```

This allows you to simplify the syntax to be like this:

```
var my_interceptor = new Interceptor();

Kernel.UseInterceptorFor<IMyClass>(
    c => c.MyMethod(),
    my_interceptor);
```

And here is another example for an extension method (based on Alexei Levenkov comment):

```
public static class MyExtentionMethods
{
    public static void UseInterceptorFor<TObject,TInterceptor>(
        this IKernel kernel,
        Expression<Action<TObject>> methodExpr)
        where TInterceptor : IInterceptor
    {
        var interceptor = kernel.Get<TInterceptor>();

        kernel.InterceptReplace<TObject>(methodExpr, inv => interceptor.Intercept(inv));
    }
}
```

Which allows you to do:

```
Kernel.UseInterceptorFor<IMyClass,Interceptor>(c => c.MyMethod());
```

Comment: It does not sound like OP if concerned with `InterceptAround`/`InterceptReplace` difference (which you may want to explain rather than saying it is solution), but rather with syntax itself...

Comment: Thanks. While it probably not what OP is looking for, but it now answers one reasonable interpretation of the question ("full control of method execution" vs. just before/after calls).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I have just added an example of how extension methods can simplify the syntax.

Comment: If you move `new Interceptor()` inside the helper method (possibly with resolving interceptor via container itself) you should achieve almost exact syntax asked by OP.

Comment: Great answer! However, single interceptor object is not thread-safe. I think we should create it inside the action like this:     inv =>
    {
     var interceptor = new TestInterceptor();
     interceptor.Intercept(inv);
    } What do you think?

Comment: I updated the answer with another example. If you make sure that `Interceptor` is registered as Transient (the default), then you would get a new instance every time.